# Custom Component MVC output in Joomla ExtJS Layout Problems

Tags: model-view-controller, dom, extjs, joomla, components

So essentially, I am working on a custom component for Joomla 2.5 which uses ExtJS to create DOM elements, inline css, etc.

But after I install and view it, it always pushes the other Joomla stuff under it. I have [live example here](http://transhumandesigns.com/joomla25/index.php?option=com_channelperformance2)

I believe my mvc structure is set up right. It can be viewed on Cloud Nine IDE at http://c9.io/alecperkey/joomla25

The administrator credentials for the Joomla25 test site are username="stack" and password="stack"... but I don't think they will be helpful since I didn't do anything with the admin side of the component.

If someone can explain what is going wrong, it would me a lot to me. I've been stuck for a few days now.

Comment: I tried loading your url - it was very, very slow, and then many, many JS errors starting in ext-all.js.  I don't think you have an MVC problem, I'd say you need to do some JS debugging

Comment: Yes the JS errors are all just 503's because I don't have this test account set up with the remote database. I suppose it is distracting to have 18 JS errors in firebug, but my issue is just simply about the layout.

Comment: I'd still say you should start there...the ExtJS is creating your DOM, it's encoutnering many errors, so there's no telling what might be awry in the DOM it's creating for you - good luck.